# Количество установок в AlarmManager

Tags: java, android

Добрый день интересует такой вопрос, как сделать несколько установок по времени с помощью AlarmManager. Допустим мне нужно 2 сигнала в 11 и 12 часов. когда я пытаюсь сделать это он только делает сигнал в 12 часов. Подскажите как решить заранее спасибо!

```
 public void startAlarm(Calendar calendar) {
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent myIntent;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,push.class);        
pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,myIntent.setAction("1"),0);
    manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);        
}
```

Comment: Покажите код. Скорее всего вы просто перезаписываете один и тот же аларм, а надо сделать разные. Вроде бы это через `action` в `Intent` делается.

Comment: Не надо код в комментариях. Добавьте его в вопрос через редактирование. А по вопросу: установите актион. Типа myIntent.setAction("1") с 1 и 2 для разных алармов

Comment: сори новичок на форуме. А можно пример не совсем понимаю как это сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По идее, должно работать как-то так:

```
public void startAlarm(Calendar calendar, String action) {
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent myIntent;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, push.class);
    myIntent.setAction(action);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
    manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

Т.е. нужно, чтобы интенты были разными и добавление `action` должно делать их разными для ОС.

Теперь можно создать два разных аларма так:

```
setAlarm(calendar0, "0");
setAlarm(calendar1, "1");
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, это решило мою проблему)